# Mssql queue implementation

Tags: node.js, sql-server, t-sql, locks

I have table `QUEUE (job_id)` on MS SQL which holds stored jobs to be done on Node.JS/Express.js (separate application, separate session)

When a row to queue is inserted (from second table trigger), I need to trigger a job in Node.js (by job id)

- I found some solutions using Service Broker, but there are limitations because of Express version of MS SQL
- A working but dirty solution is something like this (written on Node.js)

  ```
  while (1=1) {

    read queue

    if (queue not empty) {
        do job
        clear queue
    }
    wait few seconds
  }
  ```

Is there another option? To eliminate waiting a few seconds? Is it possible to stop select (for example by application lock) until queue is filled?

Comment: What limitations are stopping you from using Service Broker?

Comment: I red somewhere that you cant send messages . But after your post, I googled more and It should be possible in ine instance. I will try it. Thanks :-)

Comment: As far as I know the sole limitation is that Express editions cannot send message to other SQL Server instances if the receiver is also an Express edition. But as far as i understand your question, you don't need that. Everything is happening in one instance -- the table trigger runs there and the application connects to it, i.e. its SQL also runs there. Or what am I missing?

Comment: No, you are absolutly right :-). It should work. I am working on it :-) thanks again

Comment: Did you ever succeed in this job?